# How to use specific data from csv file with d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am making a grouped bar chart using d3. I have a csv file with the amount of people in the netherlands in the 20th century. Each row is a year. In my bar chart I only want to display the data from 1950. I have tried to achieve this by making a function that checks if the year is at least 1950, but this doesn't give me the right result. It still returns the rest of data but layerd over eachother at the beginning of the graphic. I hope someone could help me.

```
        // read in the file
        d3.csv("gender_ratio.csv", function(error, data) {
        var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Perioden"; });

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
        });

        // set the domain
        x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { 
            if (d.Perioden > 1949) {
                return d.Perioden;
            }
        }));

        // draw the bars
        Perioden.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
            .attr("height", function(d) { return h - y(d.value); })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return kleur(d.name); });
```

Comment: Is this all the code?  I don't see `x0` being set up or ever used after the domain is set.  I'm guessing there's more to it.

Comment: yes there is obviously a lot more, but I thought the problem would be located in this part. Do you think it is in another part?

Comment: CSV data is loaded as strings. You need to convert to numbers to perform the check you want to do, e.g. by (inside the `data.forEach`) `d.Perioden = +d.Perioden;`.